# How did this css put a check before the <li>

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make this todolist on my own https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_todolist.asp

But this piece of css code:

```
/* Add a "checked" mark when clicked on */
ul li.checked::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    border-color: #fff;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2px 2px 0;
    top: 10px;
    left: 16px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    height: 15px;
    width: 7px;
}
```

adds a check before the list, how does it put the check mark before the list?

Comment: It creates a pseudo element, gives it a right and bottom border, then rotates it 45 degrees.  Exactly what it says it's doing in the CSS you posted.

Comment: https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/YxKXdM

Answer (score 2):

The "check" is just the border of an empty box given a specific size, then rotated. The `::before` pseudo element goes at the beginning of the content, the width and height form a rectangle, the border puts lines on two of the four edges, then the transform rotates it so the border looks like a check. Kinda a roundabout way of doing it. They could have also just used `content: 'some checkbox char'``.

If you change the `border-width` or transform things, you'll see what I mean.